# How do I find a tr that is second inside the td OR find a td with a class

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery, jquery-selectors

I want to

1. hide the 2nd td inside a tr and,
2. get the value of the 2nd td in the future.

how do i get to the value of the 2nd td?

1. the second td inside a tr which is inside?
2. the td with a class name "hide"

How could I code this out in Jquery?

I have something like this for starters:

```
$('#todolist').each(function () {
var $table = $(this);
$('td', $table).each(function () {

---code---
```

Comment: Your question is confusing.  It would be better if you gave us an HTML example of what you want.

Comment: `$('#todolist').each`? You don't have multiple elements with the same `id` attribute, do you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve all these problems by reading the docs (especially on selectors) and the samples they contain.

See: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

And you can [play with jQuery very easily using jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/) as a sandbox.  For example, here's [a fiddle I used to prepare answers to your questions](http://jsfiddle.net/65MEx/).

#### Your specific questions:

> **I want to hide the 2nd td inside a tr**

Assuming the `tr` you want is the first one, as opposed to hiding the 2nd td in all of them...

```
$('#todolist tr:eq(0) td:eq(1)').hide();
```

> **I want to get the value of the 2nd td in the future**

Save off the `td` in a variable instead of directly executing functions against it.  Then you can [read the value using `.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/).

```
var secondItem = $('#todolist tr:eq(0) td:eq(1)');
secondItem.hide();
var value = secondItem.text();
alert(value);
```

> **how do i get to the value of ... the td with a class name "hide"**

jQuery uses CSS selector syntax.  Use [the CSS selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#value-def-identifier) for IDs.

```
var value = $('td.hide').text();
```

As for Question B1, "**how do i get to the value of the 2nd td? the second td inside a tr which is inside?**", I don't understand what you're asking...

Comment: Sorry for the weird questions.. don't really know how to express my requirements in words before. :) but you answered my questions.

Thanks!